# Get a value from one table and insert it in another SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My stored procedure is like this

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[kt_insernotes]
     (@DATASET  NVARCHAR (512)
      ,@ROWNUMBER INT
      ,@LASTCHANGED DATETIME
      ,@NOTESFILEID INT
      ,@NOTESRECID INT 
      ,@LINENUMBER NUMERIC (28, 12)
      ,@TXT  NVARCHAR (512)
      ,@DATE_   DATETIME 
      ,@USERID  INT   
    )
AS

INSERT INTO NOTES (DATASET
      ,ROWNUMBER
      ,LASTCHANGED
      ,NOTESFILEID
      ,NOTESRECID
      ,LINENUMBER
      ,TXT
      ,DATE_
      ,USERID)
values (@DATASET,@ROWNUMBER,@LASTCHANGED,@NOTESFILEID, (select ISP_EFAVORITLINE.ROWNUMBER where ISP_EFAVORITLINE.DATASET=(@DATASET)) ,@LINENUMBER ,@TXT,@DATE_,@USERID)
    RETURN
```

everything looks good for me ,but this line

```
(select ISP_EFAVORITLINE.ROWNUMBER where ISP_EFAVORITLINE.DATASET=(@DATASET))
```

throws an error

> *Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure kt_insernotes, Line 26
>
>   The multi-part identifier "ISP_EFAVORITLINE.DATASET" could not be bound.
>
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure kt_insernotes, Line 26
>
>   The multi-part identifier "ISP_EFAVORITLINE.ROWNUMBER" could not be bound.*

can any one give me a clue what went wrong?

Comment: You're inserting into `Notes` Table which is destination, I think you're missing the `from` `source` table name after values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `FROM` clause:

```
(select ISP_EFAVORITLINE.ROWNUMBER from ISP_EFAVORITLINE where ISP_EFAVORITLINE.DATASET=(@DATASET))
```

The system is seeing a table name or alias, and it doesn't know what it's meant to be bound to. It *could* just assume that you mean a table with that name, but SQL doesn't tend to do much in the way of assuming. If you want to use a table, you better have it in a `FROM` clause.

Comment: yes its a slip from my part,thanks for the help and xtra info

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can have select query in value clause:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[kt_insernotes]
              (@DATASET  NVARCHAR (512)
              ,@ROWNUMBER INT
              ,@LASTCHANGED DATETIME
              ,@NOTESFILEID INT
              ,@NOTESRECID INT 
              ,@LINENUMBER NUMERIC (28, 12)
              ,@TXT  NVARCHAR (512)
              ,@DATE_   DATETIME 
              ,@USERID  INT   
            )
AS

INSERT INTO NOTES (DATASET
                  ,ROWNUMBER
                  ,LASTCHANGED
                  ,NOTESFILEID
                  ,NOTESRECID
                  ,TXT
                  ,DATE_
                  ,USERID
                  ,LINENUMBER
                 )
select @DATASET,
       @ROWNUMBER,
       @LASTCHANGED,
       @NOTESFILEID,
       @LINENUMBER,
       @TXT,
       @DATE_,
       @USERID,
       ISP_EFAVORITLINE.ROWNUMBER 
from ISP_EFAVORITLINE
where ISP_EFAVORITLINE.DATASET=(@DATASET)

RETURN
```